# Obtener <a>este texto</a> usando BeautifulSoup4

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

He encontrado con éxito la tabla y la columna usando:

```
table = soup.find('table', class_='sortable')
table_buy_rows = table.find_all('tr')
for tr in table_buy_rows:
    td = tr.find('a')
    print(td)
```

Pero obtengo esto:

```
<a href="/wiki/Shanar" title="xxx">Y YO QUIERO ESTE TEXTO</a>
```

A partir de ahí ¿como obtengo el texto dentro de la etiqueta? He usado `print(td.text)`, `print(td.get_text)`, `print(td.string)`, pero en todas obtengo error.

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'
```

¡Cualquier sugerencia sería muy apreciada!

---

### Lo pude resolver de la siguiente manera:

```
table = soup.find('table', class_='sortable')
tbr = table.find_all('span', class_='tooltip')
for i in tbr:
    texto = i.find('a')
    print([texto.text])
```

Comment: Hola Nick, podrías compartir la url si la página es pública para poder reproducir el problema? Lo primero que se me ocurre es que algún `tr` de a tavlano tenga una etiqueta `a`.

Comment: @FJSevilla gracias por tomarte el tiempo de leer y preguntar para ofrecerme tu ayuda. Justo acabo de resolverlo:

`table = soup.find('table', class_='sortable')
tbr = table.find_all('span', class_='tooltip')
for i in tbr:
    texto = i.find('a')
    print([texto.text])`